# Ubuntu Software cannot install program

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04

i can't download any program using Ubuntu Software.

Example error defination is that(for install Kdenlive) :

**Unable to install Kdenlive:
Error while installing package: mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1 ..... '/usr/bin/bsondump'**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-tools
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```

and post the errors you are getting, if any.